# how to sent parameter to another activity when recieve sms

Tags: android

how to sent parameter to another activity after receiving SMS I try but its show error

> The method `putExtra(String, boolean)` in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (Bundle)

below is my code:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";  


    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        }

        Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
        Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("msg", str);
        l.putExtra(bundle);

        l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(l);
        Toast.makeText(context, "SucessFull Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the string directly into the intent:

```
l.putExtra("msg", str);
```

and then get it using:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
```

but if you wanna use bundles, i think here you should refere to **bundle2**:

```
Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
        Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
        bundle2.putString("msg", str);

    l.putExtras(bundle2);
```

Comment: this error  

The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (Bundle)

Comment: to pass bundle use l.putExtras(bundle2); using putExtra() you have to respect the arguments, here putExtra(String, boolean) is expecting a boolean

Answer (score 0):

Its easy using the Shared Preference. Use this following links

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bundle by using `Intent.putExtras(Bundle)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a bundle use `putExtras (Bundle extras)` and not `putExtra`